# Invariance of nabla under pure rotation

Tags: vector-analysis, transformation, invariance

The problem goes as follows: Show that, under a rotation $\vec {\nabla} = \hat{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \hat{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+ \hat{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \hat{i'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}+ \hat{j'} \frac{\partial}{\partial y'}+ \hat{k'} \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} = \vec{\nabla '} $

My approach: We know, for a pure rotation: $ \hat {i} = l_1 \hat{i'} + l_2 \hat{j'} + l_3 \hat {k'}$ and so on... where $l_i , m_i, n_i$ are the direction cosines of the old co-ordinate axes (in respective order) w.r.t the new ones. Plugging the values in, we get: $\vec {\nabla} = \hat{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \hat{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+ \hat{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \sum [l_1 \frac {\partial}{\partial x} +m_1 \frac {\partial}{\partial y} +n_1 \frac {\partial}{\partial z}] \hat{i'} = \sum \frac {\partial}{\partial x'} \hat{i'} $

Is my approach alright? Is the inference at the very end correct?

Comment: I suspect you might be on the right track, but I'm getting confused with your notation. I believe you are going for a double sum? That is what you need, but I'm not quite getting that from your notation.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I have just substituted the values under transformation. The expression is symmetric.

Comment: I have skipped a few steps in between. Final rearrangement leads to this

Comment: The vector you get between two coordinate systems is ultimately the same object, just expressed with new coordinates in a new basis: $\vec{v}=\sum_{i=1}^3 v_i\hat{e}_i=\sum_{j'=1}^3v_{j'}\hat{e}_{j'}$

This is the general rule for transforming the coordinates of a vector: $v'_{i'}=\sum_{j=1}^{3}R_{i'j}v_j$ where $R_{i'j}=\hat{i'}\cdot\hat{j}$. $R_{i'j}$ can be identified with a matrix. 

A similar rule applies for transforming basis vectors. Once you know how to transform Vector coordinates and basis vectors, you can use the machinery to prove which things are conserved under rotations.